# Getting description of failed assertion

Tags: java, unit-testing, selenium

in my test method I have 3-4 assertions, when the test is failed how can I know which assertion was failed? here is my java code...

```
assertTrue(Utilities.SomeTest(driver, UserName, Password));                
assertTrue(checkData(url, "1", "7", "2012", "30", "8", "2012"));
assertTrue(verifyNo("7", 1));
```

here my second assertion is failing (which I found after debuging the code), but in console I am getting this description.

```
Failed: java.lang.AssertionError: null
```

how can I know the exact method name which is failing, in this case checkData.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is junit, you can pass a String as the first argument to `assertTrue` which will be displayed if it fails:

```
assertTrue("Utilities test failed", Utilities.SomeTest(driver, UserName, Password));
assertTrue("checkData failed", checkData(url, "1", "7", "2012", "30", "8", "2012"));
assertTrue("verifyNo failed", verifyNo("7", 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
assertTrue(String message, boolean condition);
```

so it would print a meaningful message once assertion fails.

Basically every `assertXYZ` has a version where you can specify String as a first parameter.